# Простой рецепт webview

Tags: c, webview, c++, perl

Придумал себе задачку: сделать простую оболочку для [DbNinja](http://www.dbninja.com/). Просто захотелось иметь это в отдельном окне, а не в браузере - без тулбаров, строки состояния, закладок и т.д. Первый код, который был написан буквально за полторы минуты (при этом делающий ровно то, что  и хотелось):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Gtk2 -init;
use Gtk2::WebKit;

my $window = Gtk2::Window->new;
   $window->set_default_size( 1280, 768 );
   $window->set_default_icon_from_file( 'dbninja.png' );
   $window->set_title('DbNinja');
   $window->signal_connect( destroy => sub { Gtk2->main_quit } );

my $sw   = Gtk2::ScrolledWindow->new;
my $view = Gtk2::WebKit::WebView->new;

$sw->add( $view );
$window->add( $sw );
$view->open( 'http://127.0.0.1/dbninja/' );
$window->show_all;
Gtk2->main;
```

На этом можно было бы и остановиться. Но захотелось исследовать другие решения :) Второе, что подвернулось под руку - QtCreator. Код на Qt аналогичен, тривиален, хоть и чуть больше, написан за... ну, не полторы минуты, но сравнимо :)

[Скриншот перловой версии](http://ato.su/resizer/i/0/d/2b27a754.png)

[Скриншот Qt-версии](http://ato.su/resizer/i/4/2/d6c73d96.png)

Разница несущественна: чуть-чуть в правом верхнем углу, но это, видимо, особенности работы с webkit в Gtk и Qt.

Собственно, вопрос: на чём ещё это же можно сделать так же просто и быстро? Условия:

1. Голое окно, без адресной строки, тулбаров, закладок, строки состояния, навигации и прочего.
2. Изначальные размеры задаются при старте
3. Окно должно иметь свой заголовок, иконку, корректно ресайзиться
4. Само собой - выполнять все фукнции браузера, держать куки, фреймы/ифреймы, JavaScript и т.д.
5. Работа под Windows может быть бонусом, но ни в коем случае не единственной возможностью
6. Открываемый URL может быть произвольным, прошитым, задаваться в командной строке - это не существенно

Comment: C#/Winforms/[WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? Моно вроде бы поддерживает WinForms, нет? (Вот полный [пример](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s8ys666%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).)

Comment: Ну никак не катит в качестве "простого решения". Мне даже лень мону взгромождать ради проверки.

Comment: @klopp: почему? 80% кода там обслуживает кнопки, их можно без зазрения совести выкинуть.

Comment: Да про выкидывание кода понятно. Я про то, что сам по себе моно - никак не "обычный компонент разработчика", его ж специально ставить надо. Во всяком случае тот же Qt встречается куда чаще для решения повседневных задач:)